# Runge-Kutta method ; order of convergence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

> Write the Butcher table of the Runge-Kutta method defined by $$y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{h}{2} f(x_n, y_n) + \frac{h}{2} f(x_n + h, y_{n+1})$$ and determine its order of convergence.

---

The answer by Lutz is really helpful. Thanks. Now

$$b_1=1/2, b_2=1/2, c_1=0, c_2=1, a_{11}=0, a_{12}=0, a_{21}=1/2, a_{22}=1/2$$

Can I just use $\sum_{i=1}^{2}=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}{2}b_ic_i=1/2$ to prove the consistency order is $0$?

Comment: Yes, up to typos these are the order 2 consistency/order conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Give the function values their traditional names
$$
k_1=f(x_n,y_n),~~k_2=f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})
$$
then
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}2(k_1+k_2)
$$
and consequently also
$$
k_2=f(x_n+h,y_n+h(\tfrac12k_1+\tfrac12k_2)).
$$

Comment: There are actually many ways of representing y(n+1). So do I need to write all these down?

Comment: No, you just have to use the one for the method that was given in this task, the implicit trapezoidal method. There is only one way to write its Butcher tableau and the corresponding stages of the method.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for your answer! Could you please also give me some hints on how to compute the convergence order?

Comment: As a test, apply it to a linear system $y'=Ay$, there the method step can be explicitly computed. Compare with the exact step which uses a matrix exponential. This can be (in higher orders) too optimistic, the exact order proof goes over Taylor expansions.

Comment: Sorry. I still don’t understand. Could you please tell me whether the convergence order and the consistency order are the same thing?

Comment: Yes, for one-step methods they are the same. For multi-step method you also need at least zero-stability.

Comment: Sorry. Could you please tell me why the consistency order and the convergence order are the same for on-step method? Thanks again!

Comment: Because the propagation of the local to the global error is via an order 1 recursion equation, $e_{n+1}\le (1+Lh)e_n+h\tau_n$ which sums up to $e_n\le \frac{M}{L}(e^{Lnh}-1)$ where $M$ is a bound for the truncation errors $\tau_n=O(h^p)$ and $L$ a $y$-Lipschitz constant.